# Show only parent category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I created list of category and sub category to display in my front page. When try to display all my category and subcategory are listing. I want only my main category to list. If anyone can help in this issue. Thank you

```
<span class="ad-category">
<?php
$category = get_the_category();

if ($category[0]->category_parent == 0) {
    $tag = $category[0]->cat_ID;

    $tag_extra_fields = get_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS);
    if (isset($tag_extra_fields[$tag])) {
        $category_icon_code = $tag_extra_fields[$tag]['category_icon_code'];
        $category_icon_color = $tag_extra_fields[$tag]['category_icon_color'];
    }
} else {
    $tag = $category[0]->category_parent;

    $tag_extra_fields = get_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS);
    if (isset($tag_extra_fields[$tag])) {
        $category_icon_code = $tag_extra_fields[$tag]['category_icon_code'];
        $category_icon_color = $tag_extra_fields[$tag]['category_icon_color'];
    }

}

if(!empty($category_icon_code)) {
    ?>

    <div class="category-icon-box" style="background-color: <?php echo $category_icon_color; ?>;"><?php $category_icon = stripslashes($category_icon_code); echo $category_icon; ?></div>

    <?php
} 

$category_icon_code = "";
?>
</span>
```

Comment: Do you want to get all categories attached to a particular post or all the main categories from your blog / site?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<span class="ad-category">
<?php
$category = get_the_category();
if ($category[0]->category_parent == 1) {
   $tag = $category[0]->category_parent;

    $tag_extra_fields = get_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS);
    if (isset($tag_extra_fields[$tag])) {
    $category_icon_code = $tag_extra_fields[$tag]['category_icon_code'];
    $category_icon_color = $tag_extra_fields[$tag]['category_icon_color'];
    }
} 
if(!empty($category_icon_code)) {
    ?>

    <div class="category-icon-box" style="background-color: <?php echo $category_icon_color; ?>;"><?php $category_icon = stripslashes($category_icon_code); echo $category_icon; ?></div>

    <?php
} 

$category_icon_code = "";
?>
</span>
```